# HTML attributs which accept javascript

Tags: html, attributes, tags

The **href** attribut of the HTML tag **a** accept javascript code using the form :

```
<a href="javascript:alert('hello_from_href')"> click here </a>
```

I want to know the other HTML tags/attributs which can also hold javascript in such a way.

NB : I know about HTML Event Attributes and I don't speak about them

Comment: `<area>`. In Firefox, it's also possible to use `<link>` this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a` and `area` elements with `href` tag can be used to run javascript like this. The Javascript code works because the browser replaces the URL with the value of `href` element, and browsers allow you to run Javascript in the URL using such code.

For example, if you tried pasting this to your URL bar, it would run the javascript, and you'd get four alerts:

```
javascript:[1,2,3,4].forEach(function(t){alert(t);});
```

Basically any valid Javascript code in the following format can be run in the URL field:

```
javascript:<code>
```

I have added an example of this using area element below.

```html
<a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area">Area Element</a>
<br/>
<map name="primary">
  <area shape="circle" coords="75,75,75" href="javascript:alert('cicle1');" alt="Click to go Left">
  <area shape="circle" coords="275,75,75" href="javascript:alert('cicle2');" alt="Click to go Right">
</map>
<img usemap="#primary" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="350 x 150 pic">
```

Comment: `a` Is not the only element.
For example:

    `<button onclick="function()">Click me</button>`

Comment: Reda (OP) already covers that: *I know about HTML Event Attributes and I don't speak about them*

Comment: `a` is not the only element. `area` can also be used.

Comment: @Alohci Thanks! I didn't know that. I just added an example of that in the answer.

Comment: I also noticed that `base` and `link` also have `href` attributes, but I can't think of any way in which they could be used to run javascript through URL.

Comment: As I say above, you can use `link`, but only in Firefox. Do this `<style>body link { display:block; } body link:before {  content: 'a link'; }</style><body itemscope><link itemprop="link" href="javascript:alert('using a link element')" ></body>`